# Find element at indexs after n number of rotations

Tags: algorithm, math

This questions is from hackerrank. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem

Input:

1. an array(int[]) of n numbers
2. number(k) of rotations 1 >= k <= n
3. an array(int[]) of m size of the indexes of rotated array

Output:
an array(int[]) of m size with elements of rotated array

I have solved it with the approach of rotation which will change the position of array elements.
I was trying to solved it without changing the original array(by manipulating rotated array index mathematically). here is the method I wrote, it is working for use cases I used but on hackerrank it is showing 1 test failed.

```
private int[] withoutRotateArray(int[] input, int k, int[] checkIndex) {
        for (int i = 0; i < checkIndex.length; i++) {
            if(checkIndex[i] < k) {
                checkIndex[i] = input[input.length - (k - checkIndex[i])];
            } else {
                checkIndex[i] = input[Math.abs(k - (checkIndex[i]))];
            }
        }
        return checkIndex;
    }
```

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong in my method?

Example:

I/P array[1,2,3,4,5]

rotation number: 2

Check Index: [2,4]

O/P array[1,3]

Comment: Use some modular arithmetic. For large `k`, surely `k - (checkIndex[i])` won't be a valid index.

Comment: Solved this 3 years ago, apparently the formula I used back then was (10000 * n - k + m) % n. Guess 10000 * n to avoid negative numbers. So (m - k) % n would be good enough, if you check if the result is negative and adjust then.

Answer (score -1):

On HackerRank you should take care not to mutate any of the objects/arrays you get as arguments (unless told to do so in the challenge): often the testing code relies on the assumption that your code does not do that.

So instead of storing the result in `checkIndex`, create a new array for it, and return that.